# UISearchBar spell checking

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uisearchbar

I don't want spell checking in search bar.

The documentation about it is very simply, but use:

```
searchBar.spellCheckingType = UITextSpellCheckingTypeNo;
```

not working under iOS 5 and 7; the spell-check still exist.
What's solution of this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
[searchBar setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
```